# Updating view when SwiftData Model changes (without @Query)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-data

#### Overview

I give you a bit of context. I have an app that shows events for a certain date in a weekly view. Check the screenshot to have an idea of the UI. The part on top is an horizontal calendar that shows one week at a time. Every time the visible week changes, the data source should be updated.
Considering this, I've found difficult to use the `@Query` wrapper. The interaction are simple: when a user tap on a row (that represents a day), a sheet will be open with the possibility to add an event with a start date and an end date and a Save button. If there's no event on that day, a new one is created and assigned to the entry. If present, the event object is directly modified.
The main issue is that when an event is *modified* the change is not reflected in the view (`WeekdayRowView`). More generally, I'm not sure the approach I chose is the right one, considering I'm not using the `@Query` wrapper. If you have suggestions, I'm all ears to learn how to do the right things.

#### Code

I've included some code. I cut off all the useless code, as it would be significantly longer than this. I hope this is enough to understand the situation.
The data source is an array of `WeekdayEntry` objects, this is the code:

```swift
struct WeekdayEntry: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    let date: Date
    var event: Event?
    
    mutating func update(event: Event?) {
        self.event = event
    }
    
    static func ==(lhs: WeekdayEntry, rhs: WeekdayEntry) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.event == rhs.event
    }
}
```

`Event` is a `SwiftData` model. In my main view the structure is this:

```swift
struct EventsListView: View {
    
    @State private var dataSource: [WeekdayEntry] = []
    @State private var visibleWeek: Week
    @State private var showingSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var selectedEntryIndex: Int = 0
    private let sheetHeight: CGFloat = 200
    ...

    var body: some View {
        HorizontalWeekView(visibleWeek: $visibleWeek)
            
            headerView
                .padding(.top, 10)
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(Array(dataSource.enumerated()), id: \.1) { (index, entry) in
                    WeekdayRowView(date: entry.date, event: $dataSource[index].event)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .padding(.vertical, 5)
                        .simultaneousGesture(
                            TapGesture().onEnded {
                                print("tapped row for date \(entry.date.toString())")
                                self.showingSheet.toggle()
                                self.selectedEntryIndex = index
                            }
                        )
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 5)
            .scrollBounceBehavior(.basedOnSize)
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
            EventEditView(date: dataSource[selectedEntryIndex].date, event: $dataSource[selectedEntryIndex].event)
                .onSave({ date, from, to in
                    self.showingSheet.toggle()
                })
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .presentationDetents([.height(sheetHeight)])
                .presentationCornerRadius(20)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("events list onAppear")
            if dataSource.isEmpty {
                reloadDataSource()
            }
        }
    
    private func reloadDataSource() {
        dataSource = []
        visibleWeek.dates.sorted{ $0 < $1 }.forEach { dataSource.append(WeekdayEntry(date: $0, event: DatabaseService.shared.fetchEvent(forDate: $0))) }
    }
    
    private func reloadEventsForVisibleWeek() {
        for index in 0..<dataSource.count {
            let date = dataSource[index].date
            let updatedEntry = WeekdayEntry(date: date, event: DatabaseService.shared.fetchEvent(forDate: date))
            dataSource[index] = updatedEntry
        }
    }
}
```

This is the basic structure of `WeekdayRowView`:

```swift
struct WeekdayRowView: View {
    
    let date: Date
    @Binding var event: Event?
    @State var from: Date = Date.now
    @State var to: Date = Date.now + 1.hours
    ...
}
```

This is the basic structure of `EventEditView`:

```swift
struct EventEditView: View {
    
    let date: Date
    @Binding var event: Event?
    @State var from: Date = Date.now
    @State var to: Date = Date.now + 1.hours
    ...

    var body: some View {
        ...
        Button(action: {
            print("saving...")
            if let event {
                event.date = date
                event.from = from
                event.to = to
            } else {
                let event = Event(date: date, from: from, to: to)
                DatabaseService.shared.saveEvent(event)
                self.event = event
            }
            onSave(date, from, to)
        ...
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You need to use Query to get updated values automatically if you don't you have to fetch the values yourself

Comment: So, basically, I will have to fetch them manually and also update them manually? There's no way using Binding and State? Because I'm not able to have the rows update when a value in an Event changes. @loremipsum

Comment: Not sure if’s relevant here but you should use Bindable instead of Binding for SwiftData objects

Comment: Binding is for value types. State is a source of truth. Bindable is the Observable/reference type way of modifying objects but yes you will have to manually get updated stats from the store.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution? If so please post it.

Comment: @mskw Unfortunately no, I did not find a solution. What I'm doing is to manually refresh the array of SwiftData objects. What is useful however is to declare the SwiftData object as `@Bindable var myObject = array[i]` in the `ForEach` loop or inside the body of the view.